# Angular ngMessages change class when valid and not only on error

Tags: css, angularjs, forms, validation

It's my first time working with ngMessages and my question is if the $error object has a counterpart, something like $valid? In the angular documentation for ngMessages I only came across the $error object.

```
<form name="contactForm">

    <input ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.nameField.$error, 'valid-field': !contactForm.nameField.$error}" type="text" name="nameField" placeholder="Full name*" required>

    <div ng-messages="contactForm.nameField.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">Name is required</div>
    </div>

</form>
```

What I'm doing know is when the $error object is false I change the class to 'valid-field' but this isn't correct. This way the input field is formatted like it's always valid and that isn't supposed to be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation the ng-model, where the `$error` comes from, it also have a `$valid` state so to answer your question, yes it does :)

Documentation will also show you other validation related angular model states.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

> $valid: boolean: True if there is no error.

`ng-model` attribute should be use with each field though when here in your example the input does not have a `ng-model` which could also be source of problem.

Comment: The ng-model attribute only has to be put on the input fields and not on the form itself?

Comment: Yes, which I what I am saying, in what you posted at least there is no ```ng-model``` attribute on anything. Angular needs it to bind to the input fields.