# Angular.js ngMessages Show message when valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From here > [Angular ngMessages change class when valid and not only on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941438/angular-ngmessages-change-class-when-valid-and-not-only-on-error)

I've tried this

```
<div ng-messages="userForm.name">
    <i ng-message="$error.required" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <i ng-message="$valid" class="fa fa-exclamation-check"></i>
</div>
```

this

```
<div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
    <i ng-message="required" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <i ng-message="$valid" class="fa fa-exclamation-check"></i>
</div>
```

and this

```
<div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
    <i ng-message="$error" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <i ng-message="userForm.name.$valid" class="fa fa-exclamation-check"></i>
</div>
```

And a few more that I won't bother to list. None of them worked. Can I get a working example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngMessages` is checking list of particular type, for example if $error exists then it is checking for list of types of errors, like required, min-length, max-length etc.

In your case you are trying to use, `$valid` inside `$error`. It cannot happen because if it is valid, then it will not have an error.

I think you can simply use ng-show attribute to display messages like this

```
<div ng-show='myForm.myName.$error.required'>required</div>
<div ng-show='myForm.myName.$valid'>valid</div>
```

or In your case

```
<i ng-show='myForm.myName.$error.required' class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'></i>
<i ng-show='myForm.myName.$valid' class='fa fa-exclamation-check'></i>
```

see this example 
http://plnkr.co/edit/z1Lrz17z9qnViq9HAahg?p=preview

Comment: This is definitely what I want, gonna try it now

Comment: ...and it works, and with less syntax fluff than ngMessages